# How can I split CSV files into multiple CSV files in runtime based on file size?

Tags: hpcc, hpcc-ecl

I have been trying to split CSV files into 1GB parts and the file size of the product varies such that it won't be helpful to split in a fixed number.
 I have managed to find a way to estimate the size of the resulting CSV and to get the partitioned datasets, but I am lost on how I could save the datasets as logical files and despray them without having to limit the number of parts or spam empty outputs.
 In this case, the third part of the dataset is going to be empty, as the original file has less than 2GB and the third part would be a third gigabyte, which doesn't exist.
Adding the despray action is not an issue, it is not present due to simplification of the code.
 What am I missing? What I could use to save all dataset parts defined in runtime?
Below is the code I ran on [http://play.hpccsystems.com:8010/][1]

```
STRING sInputFile := '~class::afca::crimes_-_2001_to_present.csv';
// Specification
modLayouts := MODULE
    EXPORT STRING sTerminator := '\n';
    EXPORT lLine := {STRING Line};
    EXPORT lTaggedLine := {lLine, UNSIGNED UpToSize, UNSIGNED Part};
END;
dInput := DATASET(sInputFile, modLayouts.lLine,
  CSV(HEADING(0),SEPARATOR(''),TERMINATOR(modLayouts.sTerminator),QUOTE(''),UNICODE)
);
// Header-Data split
dProduct := dInput[2..];
STRING sHeader := dInput[1].line + modLayouts.sTerminator;
// Split config
UNSIGNED uOneGigabyte := 1000000000;
UNSIGNED uGigabytesLimit := 1;
UNSIGNED uBytesLimit := uGigabytesLimit * uOneGigabyte;
UNSIGNED uByteCount(STRING sLine) := LENGTH(sLine)+LENGTH(modLayouts.sTerminator);
// Partition
dInputTagged := ITERATE(PROJECT(dProduct,TRANSFORM(modLayouts.lTaggedLine,SELF:=LEFT,SELF:=[])),
     TRANSFORM(modLayouts.lTaggedLine,
        SELF.Line := RIGHT.Line,
        SELF.UpToSize := LEFT.UpToSize + uByteCount(RIGHT.Line),
        SELF.Part := IF(LEFT.Part=0,1,IF(SELF.UpToSize <= LEFT.Part*(uBytesLimit), LEFT.Part, LEFT.Part+1)),
        )
    );
// Results
SET OF UNSIGNED suParts := SET(SORT(TABLE(dInputTagged,{Part},Part,MERGE),Part),Part);
dPart(UNSIGNED uPart) := TABLE(dInputTagged(Part=uPart),{Line});
// Read outs
UNSIGNED uEstBytes := SUM(dInputTagged,uByteCount(dInputTagged.Line));
REAL rEstGigas := ROUND(uEstBytes/uOneGigabyte,2);
// Save and despray
aSavePartNum(UNSIGNED uPart) := FUNCTION
  RETURN IF(uPart IN suParts,
    OUTPUT(dPart(uPart),,sInputFile+'_pt'+uPart+'.csv',
           CSV(HEADING(SINGLE, sHeader),SEPARATOR(''),TERMINATOR('\n'),QUOTE(''),UNICODE)
           ,compressed,overwrite,expire(1),named('dPart_'+uPart)));
END;
// Outputs
OUTPUT(CHOOSEN(dInputTagged,1000), named('dInputTagged_sample'));
OUTPUT(sHeader,    named('sHeader'));
OUTPUT(rEstGigas,  named('rEstGigas'));
OUTPUT(uEstBytes,  named('uEstBytes'));
OUTPUT(suParts,    named('suParts'));
aSavePartNum(1);
aSavePartNum(2);
aSavePartNum(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I would do it:

```
    //This first bit just generates garbage records to play with:
IMPORT STD;

GenStr(NumChars) := FUNCTION
  Ltrs    := 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  OneChar := Ltrs[RANDOM() % 52 + 1];
  LtrD    S   := DATASET([{''}],{STRING res});
  ResDS   := NORMALIZE(LtrDS,
                           NumChars,
                       TRANSFORM({STRING res},
                                 SELF.res := OneChar));
  ResRec  := ROLLUP(ResDS,TRUE,
                    TRANSFORM({STRING res},
                              SELF.Res := TRIM(LEFT.Res) + RIGHT.Res));
  RETURN ResRec[1].Res;                           
END;  
  
//generate input records        
Rec := RECORD
  UNSIGNED8 RecID;
  STRING100 Str1;
  STRING100 Str2;
  STRING100 Str3;
END;
RecsPerNode := 200;
ds := DATASET(RecsPerNode,
              TRANSFORM(Rec,
                        SELF.RecID := (RecsPerNode * STD.system.Thorlib.Node()) + COUNTER,
                        SELF.Str1  := GenStr((RANDOM() + COUNTER) % 100 + 1),
                        SELF.Str2  := GenStr((RANDOM() + COUNTER) % 100 + 1),
                        SELF.Str3  := GenStr((RANDOM() + COUNTER) % 100 + 1)
                       ),
              LOCAL);
//*******************************************
//rest of the code is the chunk output process:     

//generate CSV file chunk rec points
MaxFileSize := 10000;  //maximum size of each output CSV file

{UNSIGNED len, UNSIGNED RecNum} BldCSVline(ds L, INTEGER C) := TRANSFORM
  line := TRIM((STRING10)L.RecID) + ',' + TRIM(L.Str1) + ',' + TRIM(L.Str3) + ',' + TRIM(L.Str3);
  SELF.len  := LENGTH(TRIM(Line)) + 2; //add 2 bytes for CRLF terminator
  SELF.RecNum := C;
END;
pds := PROJECT(ds,BldCSVline(LEFT,COUNTER));

Chunks := ROLLUP(pds,
                 LEFT.len + RIGHT.len < MaxFileSize,
                 TRANSFORM({pds},
                           SELF.len := LEFT.len + RIGHT.len,
                           SELF := RIGHT ));
Chunk1 := Chunks[1].Recnum;
Chunk2 := Chunks[2].Recnum;
Chunk3 := Chunks[3].Recnum;
Chunk4 := Chunks[4].Recnum;
OUTPUT(ds[1 .. Chunk1],,'~RTTEST::CSVtest1',CSV,OVERWRITE);
OUTPUT(ds[Chunk1+1 .. Chunk2],,'~RTTEST::CSVtest2',CSV,OVERWRITE);
OUTPUT(ds[Chunk2+1 .. Chunk3],,'~RTTEST::CSVtest3',CSV,OVERWRITE);
OUTPUT(ds[Chunk3+1 .. Chunk4],,'~RTTEST::CSVtest4',CSV,OVERWRITE);
```

HTH,

Richard